# Automatically check/uncheck all subtree nodes in extjs tree when certain node gets checked/unckecked

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, treepanel

How do I automatically check/uncheck all subtree nodes in an extjs tree when a certain node gets checked/unckecked. I already have my tree with checkboxes. The only thing missing is this check/unckeck behavior. I found this: [check child nodes of a tree when a parent is clicked [ExtJS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271177/check-child-nodes-of-a-tree-when-a-parent-is-clicked-extjs) , but it doesn't work for me because the the extjs API seems to be changed.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 23):

I found a solution:

```
oncheckchange = function(node, checked, options){
    node.cascadeBy(function(n){n.set('checked', checked);} );
};

tree.on('checkchange', oncheckchange, null);
```

Comment: This solution is correct for [ExtJs] 4.0. It doesn't work with older versions.

Comment: I'm using the `.set` method, the check changes, but the checkchange event is not fired...